# Want to send the text to the Active Window

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Want to send the text from my current vb application to the Active Window
and that text should be displayed in the text area of the active window
can anyone help me?

Comment: What active window? what vb application?

Comment: my project which is i am developing is vb application
and active window is any aother program running on system which has text box or some editable thing ex word or notepad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send WM_SETTEXT message to the text control. Like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern void SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, string lParam);

 private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x0C;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string txt = "Hello World";
  SendMessage(richTextBox1.Handle, WM_SETTEXT, 0, txt);
}
```